# How can I increment items in a list alphabetically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Python code that prints data based on a template.

In the template, each selection is preceded by empty brackets, like this:

```
-[ ] selection one
-[ ] selection two
-[ ] selection three
```

Is there a way to change my script so that it increments with letters?

Like:

```
a. selection one
b. selection two
c. selection three
```

I tried using something like `s = bytes([ch[0] + 1])` but I kept encountering a bunch of errors.

Here is my script:

```
def __str__(self):
    # show the correct order (noted by Sarah)
    self.options.sort(key=attrgetter('order'))
    # make sure it supports multiple correct selections
    correct_selection = ", ".join([
        str(selection)
        for selection
        in self.options
        if selection.correct
    ])

    # also, make sure it substitutes only the known values (see Tompei for ?)
    return _TEMPLATE.safe_substitute({
        'dilemma_ethos': self.text,
        'options': "\n".join([f'-[ ] {option}' for option in self.options]),
        'correct_selection': correct_selection,
    })
```

Comment: check [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)

Comment: You can simply iterate over `strings.lowercase_ascii`, perhaps `for letter, option in zip(strings.lowercase_ascii, self.options)` in the call to `"\n".join`.

Comment: @chepner what is `zip` for?  thanks!

Comment: @diggusbickus oh, so something like `s = bytes([chr[currentLetter] + 1])` ?

Comment: `zip` pairs elements of one iterable with elements of the other. `zip(lowercase_ascii, uppercase_ascii)` produces a stream like `('a', 'A')`, `('b', 'B')`, etc.

Comment: `zip` is the best choice here, just be sure that you don't have more than 26 options or you'll run out of letters

Comment: @chepner I see what you mean... so `'options': "\n".join([f'-{bytes([chr[zip(lowercase_ascii, uppercase_ascii)] + 1)} {option}' for option in self.options]),`

Comment: no. just  `chr` `chr(97)` returns `a`, `chr(98)` returns `b`... i gave you the link to the doc

Comment: @diggusbickus Oh my apologies...so `s = ([chr[currentLetter] + 1])` ?

Comment: no. i'm sorry i won't answer because i think you should get the basics first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you could do it assuming that the template is a string (but as noted it won't work beyond z)

```
template_1 = """-[ ] selection one
-[ ] selection two
-[ ] selection three"""

def convert(template):
    return '\n'.join([f"{chr(i + 97)}. {line[5:]}" for i, line in enumerate(template.split('\n'))])

print(convert(template_1))
```

This below does the same thing, but is easier to read:

```
template_1 = """-[ ] selection one
-[ ] selection two
-[ ] selection three"""

def convert(template):
    new_list = []
    template_list = template.split('\n')
    for count, line in enumerate(template_list):
        new_list.append(f"{chr(count + 97)}. {line[5:]}")
    separator = '\n'
    return separator.join(new_list)

print(convert(template_1))
```

The function returns with a string containing the converted template.